# Is MAC address of Android will change if rebooted or network changes?

Tags: android

IF android device rebooted or network change  MAC address will change?. I think MAC Address is unique for each device. but some where i saw MAC address changing after rebooting. if mac address will change what i need to take unique number from device.

Answer (score 0):

MAC Address is unique for all device so it never change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the MAC address is changed after reboot, only in the situation when you change your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

yes,it can change in android.you should use some of device number togheter,like screen size,hardware number,IMID,...
I try so long to find unique number bot there isn't this number.so create my app with unique number that I generate from several details from device.for example:

```
m_szDevIDShort = "35"
                + // we make this look like a valid IMEI
                Build.BOARD.length() % 10 + Build.BRAND.length() % 10
                + Build.CPU_ABI.length() % 10 + Build.DEVICE.length() % 10
                + Build.DISPLAY.length() % 10 + /* Build.HOST.length()%10 + */
                Build.ID.length() % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10
                + Build.MODEL.length() % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10 +
                /* Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 + */
                Build.HARDWARE.length() % 10; // 13 digits
```

Comment: if yes, can explain how it will change. on which condition mac address will change. can you explain me please.

Comment: see this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17657/how-to-change-the-permanent-mac-address-on-my-android-phone  . also i try this 2 years ago.in my search I saw some device have same mac address and find that 90% of device has unique but it is possible to have same number

Comment: specially I do this myself.root device ,change software number,mac address,IMEI,... and later unroot it.

Answer (score 0):

MAC address is a device binary property. Reboot is related to software. And change of network will only change your IP and DNS servers, but no change occurs to the binary. So MAC address will not change. But anyway to answer your question, the Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID) will give you a unique id of any device